# Finder method name

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, reverse-engineering, finder

I am try to find out what methods the Finder calls while drawing folder icons. I am attaching my finder process in instrument and taking CPU sample of finder process but i am unable to find method name. Do you know any other program that can record finder function calls? I am on mac os X 10.6.8.

Comment: Please zip the .trace before uploading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Time Profiler Instrument and attach it to the Finder.

Open up the finder and jump through some folders.

You should have all the methods that get called listed and I'm pretty sure the drawing part is pretty near the top.

[image: Screenshot from Instruments]